# how does this code from "The C Programming Language" work?

Tags: c, eof, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm reading "The C Programming Language (2nd ed.) and near the beginning, it has examples like this:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if(c == '\n'){
        ++n1;
```

I can see how this would work while reading from a file, and I understand this syntax... But this is just reading from the console--how does one signal end of file when entering characters from a console? I'm using Windows XP... MinGW compiler...
Anyways, was this book written for waaay earlier systems with like an EOF button or something?

### Update

well, I have one more question, that's just related to how the end-of-file works under Windows.

If I just `while(getchar()!=EOF);`, then I can just keep typing characters until I signal EOF via ^Z. But, I have to write a newline, then hit ^Z, then another newline... Why does it have to be on its own line?

Comment: Make sure you declare `c` as `int`, not `char`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows uses Ctrl-Z for EOF, and UNIX uses Ctrl-D.   See http://bytes.com/groups/c/217873-eof-windows , and excellent book choice. :)

Comment: Thanks! Haha and I'm getting it for my birthday, but I couldn't wait so I downloaded it and am having a peek. But the OCR read some words and letters so wrong, and some pages won't load, so it's not a 100% awesome experience, and I feel like I'm missing a lot of information.

Comment: I have to wait about a month, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

^Z is EOF.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer has been already given, but a typical usage would be to redirect a file to standard output:

```
program.exe < samplefile.txt
```

`samplefile.txt` is "written" to standard out and `program.exe` reads this from standard out until the EOF is reached.

Comment: Just to be clear - there is no EOF "in the file" for text files - it is provided by the OS on reading past the end of the text in the file.

Comment: @Neil: Thanks for the clarification, you are totally correct. I updated the wording to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on ^Z, the reasonn it behaves like this is because it isn't really a character, it's a signal from the operating system to the C input system. As such, it is highly dependant on the interaction between the OS and the C input system buffering. Which is a fancy way of saying that it's just the way things work, for Windows and for your particular C implementation.